# WP7: take screenshot from application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

How can i take screenshot from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/216092/take-a-screenshot-on-windows-phone-7), it seems its possible on the emulator.

Comment: Thanks! Worked solution from your link: http://blog.markarteaga.com/ScreenCaptureOnWindowsPhone7.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Taking a screenshot of your application from your application code is very simple using `WriteableBitmap`. Laurent Bugnion has a good write up here: http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/12/28/taking-a-screenshot-from-within-a-silverlight-wp7-application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Taking a screenshot from within a Silverlight #WP7 application.

```
public static void SaveToMediaLibrary(
FrameworkElement element, 
string title)
{
try
{
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.SaveJpeg(
        ms,
        (int)element.ActualWidth,
        (int)element.ActualHeight,
        0,
        100);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var lib = new MediaLibrary();
    var filePath = string.Format(title + ".jpg");
    lib.SavePicture(filePath, ms);

    MessageBox.Show(
        "Saved in your media library!",
        "Done",
        MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "There was an error. Please disconnect your phone from the computer before saving.",
        "Cannot save",
        MessageBoxButton.OK);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can take a screenshot from your app, from within your page's code and saves it to the picture library of your phone. Note that this won't capture the SysTray or the AppBar:

```
WriteableBitmap w = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(this, null); // 'this' is your current page
WriteableBitmap w2 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(480, 800);

// space for SysTray
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
    {
        w2.Pixels[i * 480 + j] = -16777216; // black #ff000000
    }
}

// actual client area
for (int i = 32; i < 728; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
    {
        w2.Pixels[i * 480 + j] = w.Pixels[(i - 32) * 480 + j];
    }
}

// space for AppBar
for (int i = 728; i < 800; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
    {
        w2.Pixels[i * 480 + j] = -16777216; // black #ff000000
    }
}
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
w2.SaveJpeg(ms, 480, 800, 0, 100);
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary lib = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary();
ms.Position = 0;
lib.SavePicture("screenshot", ms);
```

Comment: It saves it as JPEG and even though the quality is 100%, it's actually pretty bad with lost of artifacts... doesn't seem to be a way to export as PNG?

Comment: don't forget to dispose your MemoryStream! use a using statement.

Comment: I worked perfectly, but do you know how to take a screenshot of a web browser control.

Answer (score 0):

You can't i'm afraid.  If you want screenshots you need to do outside using something like the snipping tool.