# WP8: take screenshot with ApplicationBar

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can i take screenshot with ApplicationBar?
I use example from [this branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553429/wp7-take-screenshot-from-application)

But with such approach  i can't get screen shot with ApplicationBar

Answer (score 2):

The application bar is not a [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but a system control, and that is why you can't get it on a screenshot using the normal methods.

Comment: Hi Pedro, do you know some abnormal methods that work? WP7 screenshot tool from xda-developers.com uses WinAPI such as CreateCompatibleDC, CreateDIBSection, BitBlt for that. Unfortunately, unlike e.g. GetDC and GetDeviceCaps, the api is no longer presented in WP8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to bypass this limitation as those API's are locked from the public SDK... you may be able to do some automation over the emulator, but that wont solve the issue for an actual device!