# Create screenshot with app bar WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, screenshot, writeablebitmap

In my application there is a possibility to create screenshot of current view. I implement it with WriteableBitmap class. For example:

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;                WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frame, null);
BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, (int)frame.ActualWidth, (int)frame.ActualHeight, 0, 100);
    result.SetSource(stream);
}
```

The problem is that if on page, that now is displaying, there is an application bar, it doesn't display on saved image. Any ideas what should I do with this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392572/wp8-take-screenshot-with-applicationbar/15393476

Answer (score 2):

`Application` bar is not a part of your app, so, you can't do that. The only way is to ask user to make a screenshot  by pressing Windows+Camera buttons.

Comment: But as you'll know the state of the application bar in code you could always customize the captured image and add it.

Comment: Yes, that's an option too.