# wp8: take screenshot with keyboard

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, screenshot

I got a project which includes screenshot of wp8 content's root view. But if someone click a edittext and open virtual keyboard i can't get this keyboard view in my picture.I mean wp8 content's root view doesn't contain virtual keyboard.

I want it in wp8.

I use example from [this branch](http://www.markarteaga.com/screen-capture-on-windows-phone-7/)

how to do with key simulation

Thanks for your replies from now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create screenshot with app bar WP8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082167/create-screenshot-with-app-bar-wp8)

Comment: I need to check is thera are other ways to do that..