# Getting screenshots of Win CE phone in system through any programming language

Tags: windows-phone, screenshot

I want to get the screen shots of windows CE or windows 7 ,8 phones which are connected to my pc using any programming language.

I know some external tools are availble like mymobiler.But I dont want to use these tools , rather than i wanna develop my own tool same as mymobiler.

Can any one suggest me how we can achieve that....??

Comment: For Windows Phone 7 and 8, [try these previous suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553429/wp7-take-screenshot-from-application)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need different techniques for each of the different platforms you want to use. This is because they connect to the PC in different ways. WindowsCE typically uses ActiveSync, Windows Phone 7 uses the Zune software and Windows Phone 8 uses something different still.

The way you'd do it with a WinCE device would likely vary depending on the specific device in question. There are, of course, WindowsCE devices which don't even have a screen so you'll need to be careful about clearly defining what devices you are interested in.

With Windows Phone 7 & 8 you'd also need custom ROM images on the devices as the ability to access what is displayed on the screen from a connected PC is not included in the standard image that is included on retail devices.  Devices with such images are only available to a very small number of people within Microsoft.

All of this will make it very hard to achieve what you are asking. A different approach, to achieve whatever your ultimate goal is, may be required.